# how to make a json object to send it via POST api in swift 3?

Tags: ios, json, swift, post

here is the structure of my key value pair that i want to send as a parameter.

KEY is rest_order

VALUE is inside of the curly braces

```
rest_order
{

    "address":"liberty",
    "order_price":"1100",
    "fname":"rara",
    "lname":"bbaba",
    "phone":"1100",
    "order_prod":[
        {
            "prod_id":"10",
            "units":"10"
        },
        {
            "prod_id":"2",
            "units":"1"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class order_prod {

    var units : String;
    var prod_id : String;

    func toAnyObject() -> Any{
        return [
            "units": self.units,
            "prod_id": prod_id
        ]
    }
}
```

This will be the class returning you the required Dictionary in Swift 3

```
class model
{

    var order_prod = [order_prod]()
    var address : String
    var order_price : String
    var fname: String
    var lname : String
    var phone : String

    func toAnyObject() -> Any{


        var arrr = Array<Any>()
        for i in self.order_prod
        {
            arrr.append(i.toAnyObject() )
        }
        return [
            "order_prod": self.arrr,
            "address": self.address,
            "order_price" : self.order_price,
            "fname": self.fname,
            "lname": self.lname,
            "phone": self.phone
        ]
    }   
}
```